# When should I use fifo file / named pipe?

Tags: process, pipe, ipc, fifo, named

I was asked to work with fifo file as a part of a homework in a course.
When should I use fifo file with `mkfifo`commend to communitcate between process (IPC). I cant see the advantages/reasons to use it.

Answer (score 0):

When compared to socket communication (network), fifo works just like a file. To use shared memory as means of IPC, you have to manually allocate memory. FIFO communication does not need networking capabilities. It is just like file operation. Pipe is unidirectional also.